# Autocompletar nem sempre funciona no Pycharm

Tags: python, autocompletar, pygame, pycharm

Estou iniciando o uso do Pycharm, criando um teste com Pygame.

Percebo que alguns métodos do Pygame não aparecem no Autocompletar do Pycharm.

Por exemplo, se eu quero colocar um `pygame.mask.from_surface()`, ao digitar `pygame.mas` não vem nada. Mas se eu completo manualmente o `mask` e pressiono o `.`, daí aparece corretamente o auto-completar `from_surface()`.

Ex:

```
import pygame
carro = pygame.image.load("imagens/onix.png").convert_alpha()
carro_mask = pygame.mas # aqui já deveria aparece o autocompletar
```

Isto também aparece para outras situações, como por exemplo, se eu quiser usar `carro.get_rect()`, aí já nem aparece nada após teclar  `carro.`

Aqui minha configuração atual:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como corrigir isso?

Comment: atualizei minha resposta, @rogério-dec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Era um bug da versão atual.

Resolvido baixando a versão nova em [PyCharm Early Access Program](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/).

Answer (score 1):

Você instalou o `pygame`, certo?
Verificou se a configuração do interpretador python está correta? Digo, está apontando para o virtualenv ou docker que você está trabalhando?
Nas configurações do interpratador você pode inclusive ver as bibliotecas listas em suas respectivas versões.

Uma sugestão adicional seria reduzir o escopo dos imports:

```
from pygame import image
```

e etc.

UPDATE

Tentei repetir seus passos e tive o mesmo problema que você encontrou.
Fiz uma busca no google e percebi que isso é um problema mais recorrente ao uso do `pygame` do que com o PyCharm.

Inclusive, [esse problema já reportado ao PyCharm em 2014](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205815729-Pygame-unresolved-references-and-no-autocomplete) e a conclusão foi de que era um problema com a biblioteca, não com a IDE.

Há tentativas de [forçar o debugger com o cache do PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26290315/1299128), mas também não pareceu resolver quando apliquei localmente.

Parece não ter solução, eu receio.

Comment: A sugestão da redução do escopo eu particularmente não achei muito útil. Um dos motivos que uso autocompletar de IDEs (ou o motivo para não usar `vim` para programar em Java) é poder escolher não memorizar o nome dos métodos da minha classe, assim como ter acesso à documentaçao da API sem sair do amiente de desenvolvimento

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado a redução do escopo foi só uma sugestão de algo que costumo fazer e é convenção em algumas empresas, por exemplo. Mas de fato é uma discussão off-topic.
Quanto a responder à pergunta, basta apenas ficar com a primeira parte.

Comment: Editei a pergunta e coloquei minha configuração atual do Pycharm.

Comment: Abri um chamado no Jetbrains e é realmente um bug e parece que na próxima versão estará ok: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-30459