# Por que o Pycharm não mostra os métodos de uma classe?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Quero saber por que o Pycharm não mostra os métodos de uma classe ao apertar control + spaço. Normalmente as IDE'S mostram todos os métodos presente na classe. Na imagem abaixo mostro o que a IDE me sugere de métodos para qualquer classe.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/306887

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui solucionar o meu problema atualizando o interpretador do Python dentro do Pycharm.

1) Primeiro cliquei na aba superior em File ->Settings.

2) Cliquei em Project: untitled (Nome do meu projeto) -> Project interpreter -> Show All..

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3) O próximo passo foi entrar em add interpreter(+).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

4) Por fim, entrei em Virtualenv Environment, selecionei New environment, selecionei o interpretador Python em Base interprete. Depois marquei as opções e cliquei Ok.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Pycharm fez algumas atualizações do interpretador e ao acabar passou a mostrar todos os métodos pertencentes a classe. O processo é o mesmo tanto em Linux quanto em Windows.